# DRF: Pass serializer depth with a GET parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

It's possible to change a serializer depth with a GET parameter? For example calling `http://localhost:8000/api-auth/?depth=1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved it in a really simple way, assuming that views are made with class based views or viewsets:

The `serializer_class` propriety it's actually **the** serializer, it's a class, so you can access to the depth value with `serializer_class.Meta.depth`, and assign it a value from the `self.request.GET` array

Example serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

Example view:

```
class ItemList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ItemSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
      if(self.request.GET.get('depth')):
          if (10 >= int(self.request.GET.get('depth')) >= 0):
              self.serializer_class.Meta.depth = int(
                  self.request.GET.get('depth'))
      return self.serializer_class
```

Comment: This is not "safe", as the overridden depth will persist in the serializer class between requests.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to pass some extra data from view to serializer is the **serializer context**.

In DRF class-based view, you can (and, actually, should for such purposes) override `get_serializer_context()` method. In the overridden method you just add to the context, which is just a dictionary, whatever you want.

Simple example, how to do this in view:

```
class YourView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context['depth'] = self.request.query_params.get('depth', 1)
        return context
```

And the to access it in serializer:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    the_depth_from_get_param = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = [
            'the_depth_from_get_param'
        ]

    def get_the_depth_from_get_param(self, obj):
        return self.context['depth']
```

Comment: it will literally return `"the_depth_from_get_param": 1`, without any field from the model

Comment: @Fabi0_Z exactly (except the case when you'll add GET-parameter like ```?depth=42```). But this is just an example, how to pass query parameter to a serializer through serializer context.

Comment: Yeah, but the depth parameter of the serializer is defined in the Meta class, so it isn't just a simple value to display

Comment: @Fabi0_Z as far as I know, there is no magic way to define serialization depth in DRF serializers. 

But I've shown the way to make the depth value from query parameter available in serializer method field. So it can be used there to implement the required logic (nested item serializer selection, or passing the decreased ```depth``` value to the nested serializer etc).